# Android - Start a service when app is killed or finished

Tags: java, android, service

I'm working on an android project where I've to start a service every time the app is closed. That works correctly. The problem is the following: if the app is killed while is in second plane, the `onDestroy` method is performed but the service never starts. Here is the case:

- Open the app
- Pass it to second plane (by minimizing)
- From the list of app that are in second plane, I close my app using the option "Remove from list"

On the `onDestroy` method I have another method that initializes the services and the services is configured with `return Service.START_STICKY;`

I've seen several questions (for example: [START_STICKY and START_NOT_STICKY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky), [Continue service when app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018051/continue-service-when-app-is-killed) , [Starting a service from application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381977/starting-a-service-from-application-class)) but they have not worked.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot reliably detect when an app is killed. You can detect when it goes to the background, i.e. `onPause`.

Comment: But when I kill the app in the way that I showed, I can see from the log that the OnDestroy method from the main activity is being called

Comment: [onDestroy documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy())

Comment: Bullet and code formatting

Comment: Well, finally I decided to start the service every time that the application pass to second plane and stop it when is resumed. Thanks @Simas for your responses.